# Adding a clickable link to a Google Map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map that pulls info from a database and populates it with markers, name, address, etc.  In the same database is a URL called "slug". I'd like to make the Name/Address popup for each marker be a clickable link taking you to "slug".

[Here's the map so far...](http://bio-medical.com/resources/map.html)

And here's the code so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var customIcons = {
            restaurant: {
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            bar: {
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
        };

        function load() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
            downloadUrl("phpsqlsearch_genxml.php", function(data) {
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var first = markers[i].getAttribute("first");
                    var last = markers[i].getAttribute("last");
                    var line_1 = markers[i].getAttribute("line_1");
                    var line_2 = markers[i].getAttribute("line_2");
                    var line_3 = markers[i].getAttribute("line_3");
                    var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
                    var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
                    var zipcode = markers[i].getAttribute("zipcode");
                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                    var html = "<b>" + first + "\xa0" + last + "</b> <br/>" + line_1 + "<br/>" + (line_2 ? line_2 + "<br/>" : "") + (line_3 ? line_3 + "<br/>" : "") + city + "\xa0" + "," + state + "\xa0" + zipcode;
                    console.log(html);
                    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: icon.icon,
                        shadow: icon.shadow
                    });
                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                }
            });
        }

        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {}

        //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After:

```
var html = "<b>" + first + "\xa0" + last + "</b> <br/>" + line_1 + "<br/>" + (line_2 ? line_2 + "<br/>" : "") + (line_3 ? line_3 + "<br/>" : "") + city + "\xa0" + "," + state + "\xa0" + zipcode;
```

add:

```
var slug = markers[i].getAttribute("slug");
html = "<a href='" + slug + "'>" + html + "</a>";
```

This will make all the text inside the popup a clickable link

Comment: I had to add a 'var' before the second line, but this works perfectly. Thanks Jaromanda!

Comment: you shouldn't have to, it's simply re-using the already declared var html